# How to highlight table row as per threshold values in python and send email

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I need some help in Python code for formatting my table row color as per threshold values and send mail to Team.

This is my reference table

[image]

Here is the threshold:

[image]

I want this as output and send this table as body email:

[image]

Please help on achieving the same. Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Where is your code? what kind of table? how is the table rendered? pandas? excel? html? this question needs way more info.

Comment: So what have you tried, where is your code, research and attempt to solve the problem?

Comment: this website is not a coding service... what have you tried? this is how you could do conditional formatting with the xlsxwriter library... https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_conditional_format.html Here is a link to send an e-mail with python: https://realpython.com/python-send-email/ ... now we have put in equivalent effort...